# How to initial load UITableView then observe Firebase node for changes to refresh tableview in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

I am loading a `UITableView` with `User` data being fetched from `Firebase` initially using `observeSingleEvent` which I understand does not attach an observer after the initial read.

I also have an icon in each cell that updates when the user is online/offline. For this, I am attaching the observer to `observe` any changes to the specific `User` child node in my `willDisplay` cell delegate method and removing the observer in the `didEndDisplaying` method.

This is my first time doing this and is working correctly, but before I proceed I want to know if this is the industry standard way of initially loading data then observing changes so that the view can be updated accordingly for each cell.

**`cellForRowAt` method which dequeues and configures a cell:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ConversationsListCell", for: indexPath) as? ConversationsListCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]


        DataService.run.getUserInfo(forUserId: message.chatPartnerId()!) { (user) in
            cell.configureCell(message: message, user: user)
        }
        return cell

    }//end func
```

**`willDisplay` method attaches an observer at the specific child node and triggers a tableView.reload() if there are any changes to the node:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]

        DataService.run.observeUserNodeChages(forId: message.chatPartnerId()!) { (user) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }//end func
```

**`didEndDisplaying` method removes the observer attached by the `willDisplay` method:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row < messages.count {

            let message = messages[indexPath.row]
            DataService.run.removeObserveUserNodeChages(forId: message.chatPartnerId()!)
        }

    }//end func
```

**`observeUserNodeChages` which listens for any changes at the specific `uid` child node**

```
func observeUserNodeChages (forId: String, handler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

        print("inside observeUserNodeChages forId:\(forId)")

        conversationListHandle = REF_USERS.child(forId).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

           handler(true)

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }//end func
```

**`user` node Firebase structure**

[image]

Comment: We really need to see the code your using to observe the Firebase nodes. It’s also a bit unclear why your using delegates, removing the observer and the purpose of the code in the question as it’s lacking a bit of context. Typically you would add an .childChanged observer to Firebase which will notify you of changes and pass the node that changed to your app. From there you would update the tableview data source and reload the affected cells if needed. Can you clarify the question, add code to provide context and also include your Firebase structure so we can see what data your working with?

Comment: thanks for your response @Jay my question is about whether my implementation is best approach. The `uitable` is populated by a list of `messages` sent to a user which contains the sender `uid`, I use the `uid` to then fetch the `user` details from Firebase in my `cellForRowAt` using `observeSingleEvent .value`. So my logic is to set an observer at a lower level in the `users` node in my `willDisplay` and listen for any changes instead of listening to all user changes I only want to know about the changes for that particular user node. If there are changes then reload the tableview.

Comment: I would say that's not a good implementation as your tableView and UI responsiveness is dependent on your internet connection. That can make scrolling for example excruciatingly slow. You should not ping Firebase per cell - that data should already be present so as your tableView refreshes, you are not hitting the internet repeatedly. Best practice is to populate your tableView dataSource from Firebase and then only update that dataSource when you receive an event from Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if this is the industry standard way

That is not the industry standard way and should be avoided as it will cause flicker and slow response from your UI. However, when it comes to coding, there isn't typically a 'standard' as the code you write to solve a problem will vary depending on the use case and needed result.

Your tableView dataSource should be initially populated from Firebase and then updated when there is a change; that will be initiated by a Firebase event. Once the dataSource has been updated, then refresh the tableView.

That will keep the app responsive and your users happy.

The other thing is it seems you're attaching multiple observers within the same (users) node. That may not be necessary; attach your observers to the /users node and you will be then notified of added, changed or removed events and whichever user was affected will be passed to the firebase closure as a snapshot.

Comment: one question though, say I have 10,000 users in Firebase and they are constantly going on/offline therefore updating Firebase every time this happens my app would receive those updated `user` nodes every time also. And since I am only loading `user` data for say 100 users, receiving an update for all the other 9,900 users seems so unnecessary for my app to process. Is your suggested approach still the best approach, is there a way to only listen to updates on the 100 users that my app would be interested in?

Comment: @Roggie 10,000 users is not really a big deal. As the status of each users changes a small amount of data is fed to the app via the snapshot and the tableView is updated accordingly. You could even just update the cell of the row if needed but in general, just a reload or refresh of that row is adequate. If you are only loading a subset of users are a time, you could observe just that subset if needed. I know the knee-jerk reaction is to avoid monitoring 10,000 users but the reality is the are not all going to go off/on line at the same time and it would probably be a smaller number.